# How can a Tab or Enter Key jump a Control in QML

Tags: qt, qml

What i want to do here is to prevent the `tab` and `enter` to jump the focus to a specific control but go to the next.

So for example lets say i have 3 sequencial `TextField`
i'm focused on the first `TextField` now i press `tab` and instead of jumping to the second `TextField` the focus goes to the third `TextField`.

A full code example:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
    import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    title: "Stack"
    visible: true
    width: 1400

    Page {
        id: page
        anchors.fill: parent
        property int responsiveWidth: 1000
        property int maximumWidth: 900

        ScrollView {
            id:configScroll
            anchors.fill: parent
            function scrollToY(y) { 
                configScroll.flickableItem.contentY = y-30
            }
            GridLayout {
                columns: 2
                Keys.onPressed: {
                    if(event.key==Qt.Key_Return)
                    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; ++i)
                        if (children[i].focus) {
                            children[i].nextItemInFocusChain().forceActiveFocus()
                            break
                        }
                }
                width: page.width > page.responsiveWidth ? page.maximumWidth : page.width
                anchors.top: parent.top
                anchors.left: parent.left
                anchors.leftMargin: page.width > page.responsiveWidth ? (page.width - childrenRect.width)/2 : 10
                anchors.rightMargin: page.width > page.responsiveWidth ? 0 : 10


                    Label {
                        text: "Company Name"
                        color: "red"
                        Layout.fillWidth: true
                    }

                    TextField  {
                        objectName: "company_name"
                        font.bold: true
                        Layout.fillWidth: true
                        Layout.rightMargin: 10
                        onFocusChanged: if(focus) { configScroll.scrollToY(y); }
                    }


                    Label {
                        text: "tab or enter passes this TextField"
                        color: "red"
                        Layout.fillWidth: true
                    }

                    TextField  {
                        objectName: "company_name2"
                        font.bold: true
                        Layout.fillWidth: true
                        Layout.rightMargin: 10
                        onFocusChanged: if(focus) { configScroll.scrollToY(y); }
                    }

                    Label {
                        text: "label"
                        color: "red"
                        Layout.fillWidth: true
                    }

                    TextField  {
                        objectName: "company_name"
                        font.bold: true
                        Layout.fillWidth: true
                        Layout.rightMargin: 10
                        onFocusChanged: if(focus) { configScroll.scrollToY(y); }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @eyllanesc it's the id of ```ScrollView``` i forgot it

Comment: @eyllanesc what version are u using of qt? im using qt 5.12. This code is running. what errors you get?

Comment: @eyllanesc what kind of errors? i runned it now and it is ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the QML Type `KeyNavigation` to setup custom navigation, take a look at the documentation: [KeyNavigation QML Type](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-keynavigation.html)
You can set the KeyNavigation.tab property to navigate to a specific id like this:

```
TextField  {
    id: field1
    objectName: "company_name"
    font.bold: true
    Layout.fillWidth: true
    Layout.rightMargin: 10
    onFocusChanged: if(focus) { configScroll.scrollToY(y); }
    KeyNavigation.tab: field3
}
```

For navigation with enter-key here is a solution for this specific situation:

```
children[i].nextItemInFocusChain().nextItemInFocusChain().forceActiveFocus()
```

Comment: Nope! Use `KeyNavigation.tab` attached property instead of `children[i].nextItemInFocusChain().nextItemInFocusChain()`. You already set next item so why you used `children[i].nextItemInFocusChain().nextItemInFocusChain()` ?!

Comment: @S.M.Mousavi How to use KeyNavigation.tab for enter key?!